# How to link and compile libzip with c++ on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, c, zip, zlib

I am trying to decompress a zip using c++, an am using libzip for that purpose. I downloaded and extracted the libzip files to a folder, but now i want to know how should I link these to a c++ file in another folder and compile it?

Comment: First you have to compile the library. Usually with `./configure && make`

Comment: I did that, and just now was able to link to the lib folder. But now it gives me 'undefined reference to `zip_open'' and other errors.

Comment: the library name is `libz.so` so the respective linking flag is `-lz`, but first configure + make install

Comment: @bobahThe library name is lib, and contains zip.h

Comment: Also i am not particularly sure if the install worked because it tried to install it in home/usr/bin, and exited saying 'Permission denied'

Comment: @aceBox The library and header files are different. It shouldn't 'contain' zip.h usually you #include the header and then make sure you link with the lib

Comment: @aceBox Probably easiest is to  install into `/usr/local` or if you use your home dir it needs to exist. `/home/usr/bin` sounds like it should be `/home/aceBox/usr/bin`